# Рисование кривых и многоугольников на Canvas

Tags: android, java

Работаю с 2d-графикой в Android с помощью класса Canvas. Существуют ли способы, позволяющие рисовать:

1. Кривую второго порядка (quadratic curve)
2. Кривую третьего порядка (cubic curve)
3. Многоугольник (полигон) из массива точек [x, y]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого существует класс [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html).

Многоугольник так:

```
Path polygon = new Path();
polygon.moveTo(x1, y1);
polygon.lineTo(x2, y2);
polygon.lineTo(x3, y3);
polygon.lineTo(x4, y4);
polygon.lineTo(x5, y5);
new Canvas().drawPath(polygon, new Paint());
```

Кривые второго и третьего порядка - так:

```
Path curve = new Path();
curve.moveTo(x1, y1);
curve.quadTo(x2, y2, x3, y3);
//или
//curve.cubicTo(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)
new Canvas().drawPath(curve, new Paint());
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно рисовать с помощью OpenGL ES. Ссылок приводить не буду, ибо полно материала везде.

Кроме того, Вы можете использовать сторонние библиотеки(может найдете что-тл полезное и там):

- [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)
- [AchartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)
- [Android Plot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart)

А вообще, если Вам это необходимо для игр, то есть много хороших игровых движков для дроида(но не только).

Comment: Я пока пишу небольшое приложение для себя. В данном случае это не игра. С OpenGL никогда не работал. Поэтому плохо представляю разницу между использованием примеров из ответа wild frog и OpenGL. Могу предположить, что в вашем варианте больше возможностей и performance лучше.

Comment: То что быстрее бесспорно, так как это обертки вокруг Сишных api. Но проще не будет в использовании, если брать чистый OpenGL ES. Я потому и говорил про движки игровые, ибо там попроще с этим, правда без мат подготовки тоже не очень.